# imagick текст под размер изображения

Tags: php, imagick

Пишу бота для телеграмм, столкнулся с такой проблемой что не могу автоматически подогнать размер шрифта под изображение. Пользователь может прислать любой размер изображения от 300x300px до 2500px и соответственно на больших изображениях текста практически не видно. На маленьких он огромен. Делать условия типа 
`if(imgWidth == 300 && imgHeight = 300) $textSize = 12;` 
не самое удачное решение, уверен что есть более простой способ. В общем буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Цели не очень известны, но как вариант я бы наверное сделал так, создавал бы большое пустое изображение с требуемым текстом и прозрачным фоном, масштабировал его в зависимости от размера пришедшего изображения и накладывал бы на пришедшее изображение.

Comment: цель простая. Пользователь пишет текст, затем кидает изображение и данный текст накладывается на картинку. При таком подходе качество будет ужас как теряться если я картинку 500х500 к примеру, буду масштабировать на 2600px. Мне почему то кажется с помощью queryFontMetrics можно реализовать подобное. Но пока не понял как.

Comment: @VikiMayson добавил ответ, думаю решает твой вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию относительную размеров шрифта и размера картинки

```
function relationship ($value)
{
    if ($value >= 300 && $value <= 2500)
    {
        $size = 6;
        return round($size += $value / 100 * 2);  
    }

}
```

**Например**, мы берем размер **300x300**, пишем

`$size = relationship(300);` // получаем размер текста **12**

`$size = relationship(400);` // получаем размер текста **14**

Думаю принцип понятен, далее можешь сам изменить функцию под свои значения